Blade button doesn't generate well on preprod
I have a very simple table with different buttons on each line that are all blade components, each of these generate a form with a submit button to redirect to another page.
Yet for some reason my "x-buttons.delete" component only generate the  tag and not the form.
Also, on my local vm it work just well, but this only happen on my preprod server.
I know I could just remove the not-working form and put a  tag in the button but I'm still wondering why is it doing that?
Here's how the component is called in the table
<td>
    <x-buttons.delete class="" route="{{route('censored.delete',['id'=>$censored->id])}}"></x-buttons.delete>
</td>

Here's what's inside the component
<form method="post" action="{{$route}}">
    @csrf
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm {{$class}}" type="submit">
        {!! $slot=='' ? '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>' : $slot !!}
    </button>
</form>


And here's the generated html in the browser :
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="censoredTokenLol" autocomplete="off">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm " type="submit">
        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </button>
</td>

Every other buttons on the table is the same, only difference is the route and the fontawesome icon
